# get region from xml file using xpath

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

i have one xml file with content of `region, state, city name`

```
<childrens>
    <child_1 entity_id="1" value="Region">
        <child_2 entity_id="2" value="Asia">
            <child_3 entity_id="3" value="Gujarat">
                <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Ahemdabad" />
            </child_3>
        </child_2>
    </child_1>
</childrens>
```

i am try to get region name if entered city name is match in xml file.

here is one variable there value in `Ahemdabad` (city Name)

here is my xpath:-

```
value = 'Ahemdabad';
            var xPath = '//*[@value= "' + value+'"]' + 
                            '/../../@entity_id';
```

when i try City name into direct xpath as a string its work.

```
            var xPath = '//*[@value= "Ahemdabad"]' + 
                            '/../../@entity_id';
```

its not return me anything .
Please help me to solve my xpath Problem.
thanks.

Comment: I do not see what the problem is, seem sot work. Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LwQeM/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Guess the problem is with the declaration syntax. When using xpath in Xquery we declare variable as
let $var1 = "Ahemdabad"

and in case XSLT is used declaration is made like

value

And the declared variable is addressed in the necessary location. Can you please explain how are you using it?